# Sqoop import fail throwing Exception

Tags: mysql, hadoop, mysql-connector, sqoop

Sqoop import fail throwing Exception in thread "main"

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.toLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.toLowerCase(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.addToClasspathIfNotJar(MRApps.java:306)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.util.MRApps.setClasspath(MRApps.java:271)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.createApplicationSubmissionContext(YARNRunner.java:454)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YARNRunner.submitJob(YARNRunner.java:285)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.JobSubmitter.submitJobInternal(JobSubmitter.java:240)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1290)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job$10.run(Job.java:1287)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1642)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:1287)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:1308)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.doSubmitJob(ImportJobBase.java:203)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runJob(ImportJobBase.java:176)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.ImportJobBase.runImport(ImportJobBase.java:273)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.SqlManager.importTable(SqlManager.java:692)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.manager.MySQLManager.importTable(MySQLManager.java:127)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:512)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:620)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:147)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:183)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:234)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:243)
>           at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:252)

Comment: Show your command please

Comment: sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://(local host ip)/linoxide --username karthik --password karthik --table employee --m 1

Comment: try to use -m 1 (only one dash)

Comment: error remains same